# GCC does not compile

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have a MAC OS Mojave machine and gcc does not work on it. When i run the following code it does nothing and goes to new terminal line

```
 #import <iostream>;
  using namespace std;
  int main() {
     cout << "Hello World!!";
     return 0;
  }
```

PLS HELP!!
I even tried using code from w3Schools

Comment: Hello, what command did you run ? Did gcc give a message ?

Comment: I use in bult mac terminal and no it does not give a error message; @MartinMorterol

Comment: @UrTechTips Also you should write `std::cout `.

Comment: Also don't put the `;` after `#import <iostream>` (also I never see `#import` used ever and I think it's not as portable as `#include` and deprecated, so use `#include`)

Comment: @UrTechTips It's hard to believe that you don't receive any error messages like here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bffc02c5f9db0f6

Comment: But even after getting the code from w3schools it doesnot work it just does nothing no errors even.

Comment: Please cut-and-paste the **exact** output from your terminal when you compile and run the code.

Comment: Also, do you do `./file-name` after compiling? The compiler won't run the code for you too.

Comment: It is not the problem, but are you sure your compiler is GCC? Xcode and Apple development command line tools install *Clang* and not *GCC* on macOS. There is a symlink of `gcc` to `clang` which may you think you invoke GCC while you are in fact calling Clang.

Comment: Please read [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Your code had some errors. `#import` is deprecated, use `#include` instead. You don't need a semicolon after `#include` statements. Also, you need to use << to give "Hello World!!" to `cout`, not >>. If you don't use `using namespace std;`, you need to specify the namespace for `cout`. In this case, it would be `std::cout`.

Here's your corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello World!!";
   return 0;
}
```

2. gcc (or g++, since you're working with C++) doesn't run code after you compile it. If you're just running something like `g++ main.cpp`, g++ will generate a file called a.out. This is your compiled binary. To run it in the terminal, type `./a.out` in your terminal and press enter.